Hydrostatic pressure at the water surface in the draining tank problem
Given a basic draining tank problem in fluid mechanics, let the height of the tank be $h$. The open area of the surface at the top of the tank is much larger than the orifice of the draining pipe at the bottom. Using the Bernoulli principle, we can state that the total pressure acting on a particle at the surface equals the total pressure acting on a particle coming out of the pipe at the bottom.
The Bernoulli equation for this scenario is:
$
P_1 + \frac{\rho}{2} V_1^2 + \rho g h_1 = P_2 + \frac{\rho}{2} V_2^2 + \rho g h_2
$
where:

$P_1$ is the static pressure act on particle at the water surface on top,
$P_2$ is the pressure of the particle coming out of the draining pipe at the bottom,
$\rho$ is the density of the fluid,
$V_1$ and $V_2$ are the velocities at the top and bottom respectively,
$h_1$ and $h_2$ are the heights of the top and bottom respectively.

I see all the explanation video online solving this problem and they automatically give $h_1=h$ and $h_2 = 0$. They only say that because of relative position that $h_1$ is above $h_2$. They also say $\rho*g*h$ represents potential energy of particle at top.
However, if we close the draining pipe, and ask what is the hydrostatic pressure at the bottom of the tank then the hydrostatic pressure here is $\rho*g*h$, this time we use the whole height $h$ of water and not $0$, while still talking about the bottom. And i also understand because this represent the pressure coming from the mass of the column of water above pressing down on the bottom layer of tank. And the same term $\rho*g*h_1$ of tank at top becomes $0$ because basically nothing pressing down on it.
However the main question is that why in the draining tank, suddenly the value of $h_2$ becomes $0$ instead of $h$ like when the pipe is closed? And also the hydrostatic pressure $\rho*g*h_1 = 0$ of the particle at surface suddenly gain so much energy out of no where and becomes potential energy $\rho*g*h$. It seems like in the closed tank, we measure "h" from top to bottom and in draining tank, we measure it from bottom to up. This arbitrary in choosing the coordinate system seems unreliable to me. Why can't use the same general coordinate to solve for both case. How do we know when to treat it as potential energy, when to treat it as hydrostatic pressure $= 0$. I know there must be a reason why the first people did that in the first place, but no one seems to be able to explain the orginal "why" yet to me.

At the bottom ((h_2=0$), $\rho g h_2$ is always zero.

@ChetMiller, then how do you explain the hydrostatic pressure act on particle at the bottom of a stand still tank? I genuinely don't understnad because that would make hydrostatic pressure at the bottom 0 if thats what you're saying?

What you are missing is that, at the bottom of the tank in close proximity to the exit hole, there is a small region in which the flow accelerates from 0 over most of the bottom of the tank to $v_2$ at the very entrance to the exit hole.  As the flow accelerates, its pressure decreases from $\rho g h_1$ over most of the bottom of the tank to 0 (gauge) at the entrance to the exit hole.  So we have $$\rho g h_1=\rho v_2^2/2$$
So there are really 3 regions of interest:  most of the tank, the converting flow region in the tank immediately adjacent to the exit tube, and the exit tube.
ADDENDUM
I think you are confused about the term "hydrostatic pressure.."  $\rho g h_1$ is not the hydrostatic pressure at point 1.  Hydrostatic pressure (neglecting flow) is the pressure at a depth d below the free surface.  Suppose that we want to use the Bernoulli equation to determine the hydrostatic pressure at at point 3, situated somewhere below the water surface (not necessarily the bottom of the tank) where the depth below the surface is d.  Then we would write $$p_1+\rho g h_1=p_3+\rho g h_3$$ where $h_1$ and $h_3$ are the elevations above the base of the tank.  Then solving for the hydrostatic pressure at point 3, we would obtain $$p_3=\rho g (h_1-h_3)$$But, $h_1-h_3=d$.  So the hydrostatic pressure at point 3 would be $$p_3=\rho g d$$This is what we expected.

i okay then please if possible i just want to ask a simple question:
why is the hydrostatic pressure of the particle on top of water surface, going from $0$ to maximum potential energy $\rho gh$. i am not asking about the phenomenon as i understand its conversion between different energy type. however what i want somebody to explain, is that without using "different" energy type", is there a way to explain just by using the same energy type which is "hydrostatic pressure", completely not touching the concept of potential energy. because if stick to Bernouli equa, there is no potential energy.

The hydrostatic pressure at the top of the water surface is not $\rho g h$.  It is always 0.

Right, then i completely agree with this point of yours, but then why the term "$\rho gh$" of point 1 (the point on top of water surface) when being put in the whole Bernouli equation would retain its value as $\rho gh$? this is the confusing part about the Bernouli equation for me. Because the term "$\rho gh$" is called the hydrostatic pressure in the Bernouli equation, when substitute it for the point on surface water, people always say it is $\rho gh$, but clearly if taken out of Bernouli equation and ask what is the hydrostatic pressure that is pressing particle on top then clearly its $0$

See the ADDENDUM to my answer.

Your question is just English and mostly your own misunderstandings.
$$
\begin{align}
\tag1P_1+\frac12\rho V_1^2+\rho gh_1&=P_2+\frac12\rho V_2^2+\rho gh_2\\
\tag2h_1=h\qquad&\bigwedge\qquad h_2=0\\
\tag3P_1+\frac12\rho V_1^2+\rho gh&=P_2+\frac12\rho V_2^2
\end  {align}
$$
Case 1: $P_2\approx P_\text{atm}=P_1\qquad\implies\qquad \frac12\rho V_1^2+\rho gh=\frac12\rho V_2^2\tag4$
Case 2:

However with the same tank, if we close the draining pipe, and ask what is the hydrostatic pressure at the bottom of the tank

i.e. $V_2=0=V_1\qquad\implies\qquad P_2-P_1=\rho gh\tag5$ and if $P_1\ll\rho gh$ then $P_2\approx\rho gh$

In both cases, $h_1=h\qquad\bigwedge\qquad h_2=0$ and everything is internally consistent. It is just that you are misunderstanding and it is you that is inconsistent with the system that is being taught to you.

I'm sorry for asking but I still don't wuite understand your explanation sir.
First I assume your case 1 is talking about the flowing case, and I stated that point 1 is at the surface, point 2 is at bottom, then shouldn't your final equation is $\rho gh$ = $frac{1}{2}*\rho * (V_2)^2$
Second is case 2: you said $P_2$ almost equals $\rho gh$ but then you say that on both case, $h_2 = 0$ which make your conclusion of $\rho gh = 0$ isn't it?

In the flowing case you cannot get $V_1$ to be exactly zero. But yes, if the area is very big at the top surface and tiny at the bottom hole, then $V_1\to0$ and you get the result. Case 2 the $\rho gh$ comes from $h_1=h$ because $h_2=0$
